# Python Web scrape a page that redirects to other page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am having a difficult time in scraping contents of a web page.

To explain this here's my Python code:

```py
response = requests.post('http://a836-acris.nyc.gov/bblsearch/bblsearch.asp?borough=1&block=733&lot=66',{'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

**This gives me an HTML page containing a form(not containing the final page):**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="bbldata" action="https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/BBLResult" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_borough" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_borough_name" value="MANHATTAN / NEW YORK" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_block" value="733"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_block_value" value="733"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_lot" value="66"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_lot_value" value="66"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_unit" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_selectdate" value=""/>
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hid_datefromm"  VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hid_datefromd"  VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hid_datefromy"  VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hid_datetom"  VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hid_datetod"  VALUE="">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="hid_datetoy"  VALUE="">
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_doctype" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_doctype_name" value="All Document Classes"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_max_rows" value="10"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_page" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_ReqID" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_SearchType" value="BBL"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_ISIntranet" value="N"/>    
    <input type="hidden" name="hid_sort" value=""/>    
    </form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    document.bbldata.submit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**However if in the browser you enter this url you ultimately get this webpage after the script in the HTML has been loaded, and this has to be scraped:**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML table in your example is showing the data you need to post. As I think you're aware, the URL you're using is acutally the *referer*. So, you need to:

```
# 1. Create a payload
payload = {
        'hid_borough': 1,
        'hid_borough_name': 'MANHATTAN / NEW YORK',
        'hid_block': 733,
        'hid_block_value': 733,
        'hid_lot': 66,
        'hid_lot_value': 66,
        'hid_doctype_name': 'All Document Classes',
        'hid_max_rows': 10,
        'hid_page': 1,
        'hid_SearchType': 'BBL',
        'hid_ISIntranet': 'N'
        }

# 2. Add the correct referer to your headers
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
       'referer': 'http://a836-acris.nyc.gov/bblsearch/bblsearch.asp?borough=1&block=733&lot=66'}

# 3. Add payload and headers to the post
redirect = 'https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/BBLResult'
result = requests.post(redirect, data=payload, headers=header)

print result.url
https://a836-acris.nyc.gov/DS/DocumentSearch/BBLResult
```